# Какие способы существуют импорта кода из одного html в текущий посредством js?

Tags: javascript, html, импорт

Какие вы знаете способы вставлять шаблон в текущий html?

У меня есть куски кода, которые используются на каждой странице, плюс модальное окно (определенное\одинаковое). Я хочу, чтобы одни куски кода из других файлов вставлялись в body при загрузке, а другие по клику. Я пока что пытаюсь использовать XMLHttpRequest, но кажется оно работает только для одного элемента (в функции по клику модалка не вставляется) и идея использовать innerHTML, что думаю некорректно.

Comment: в процессе сборки или в рантайм?

Comment: @У меня есть куски кода, которые используются на каждой странице, плюс модальное окно (определенное\одинаковое). Я хочу, чтобы одни куски кода из других файлов вставлялись в body при загрузке, а другие по клику. Я пока что пытаюсь использовать XMLHttpRequest, но кажется оно работает только для одного элемента (в функции по клику модалка не вставляется) и идея использовать innerHTML, что думаю некорректно

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос =)

Comment: Я бы советовал использовать плавающий фрейм